How to solve (gcloud.compute.scp) All sources must be local files when destination is remote ERROR?
I have checked every solution on stackoverflow but I can't seem to figure out why my commands are not working.
When I do gcloud compute scp  '\Users\pcsst\OneDrive\Documents\lib-backend.jar' pcssteffi@liby-vm:/home/pcssteffi I am getting  No such file or directory error.
When I try to be more specific gcloud compute scp "C:/Users/pcsst/OneDrive/Documents/lib-backend.jar" pcssteffi@liby-vm:/home/pcssteffi, I am getting (gcloud.compute.scp) All sources must be local files when destination is remote.  Got sources: [C:/Users/pcsst/OneDrive/Documents/lib-backend.jar], destination: pcssteffi@liby-vm:/home/pcssteffi ERROR
I have specified the drive as C drive and I am getting another error. What does it mean by sources must be local files and how can I resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Does this answer your question? How to solve "Request had insufficient authentication scopes" Error?

nope that's a different error about authentication scopes @DazWilkin

Are you running gcloud compute scp on a Windows or Linux (on Windows) host? I suspect you cannot use Windows folder paths (i.e. backslashes) even when running gcloud compute scp on Windows. Replace the backslashes with slashes. Try running the command with --verbosity=debug to get the detailed underlying scp logging.
